# Как перезаписать ветку на удаленном сервере Git?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

Сделал несколько коммитов и залил все на Gitlab. Так что ветки мастер и ориджин мастер были на последнем коммите. Заметил опечатку в последнем коммите и локально в ветке мастер переименовал его. После этого сделал еще несколько коммитов локально. Пытаюсь все это снова залить на Gitlab, но выдает ошибку. Пишет, что ветка origin master существует, но среди числа существующих коммитов ее нет и залить на нее ничего не получается. Через git log показываются только локальные коммиты. Как перезаписать данные из ветки master в origin master?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что выдаёт git status и git push

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: $ git push
To http://repo.champer.ru/xxx/xxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://repo.champer.ru/xxx/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Ну так вывод git status вам на чистом английском говорит что надо сделать. "Вы на ветке master, ваша ветка и 'origin/master' разошлись и имеют 3 и 1 разный коммит. (используйте git pull чтобы слить изменения из удалённой ветке в вашу). Нечего коммитить"

Comment: т.е. сначала делаете git pull. Сливаете изменения, если будут конфликты решаете их. Потом делаете git push.

Comment: Ну так а git pull не сотрет таким образом последние локальные коммиты?

Comment: Не сотрёт. git pull получает изменения из удалённого репозитория и сливает с вашей локальной веткой (по сути последовательный вызов git fetch и git merge)

Comment: $ git pull
Auto-merging src/scss/workout.scss
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in src/scss/workout.scss
Auto-merging src/scss/01_shared.scss
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/scss/01_shared.scss
Auto-merging public/js/script.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/js/script.js
Auto-merging public/index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/index.html
Auto-merging public/css/style.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/css/style.css
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: Теперь надо решить конфликты и сделать коммит

Comment: Нужно зайти в эти файлы, все в них поправить и просто сохранить или что-то еще?

Comment: По этому поводу лучше почитайте про решение конфликтов. Но вообще да там в них сейчас что-то типа: <<<<<<< HEAD ...... ======== ...... >>>>>>> master. Надо вручную оставить только один вариант и потом закоммитить.

Comment: Это получилось и origin master появился, но теперь в общем списке коммитов остался коммит с неправильным названием.

Comment: Для переименования можно использовать git rebase --interactive и git commit --amend. https://habr.com/ru/post/201922/

Comment: Локально запускаете `git pull —rebase ...`, получите на выходе разницу с оригиналом в чистом виде, все эти back-merges к добру не приводят.